# Sylow Thm for infinite group

Tags: group-theory

I’m trying to prove:
‘Given a sylow p-subgp K of G(can be infinte)
suppose G/N(K) (or equivalently Cl(K)) is finite.
Then every sylow p-subgps are contained in
Cl(K), and |Cl(K)|=1+pk for some nonnegative integer k.’

I found this on Wiki, and tried to solve it by generalizing
the concepts which I have used to prove Sylow thm in
finite gp (-concepts using conjugacy class).

I already proved the following facts: (by using cauchy’s storng thm)

1. If G is a p-gp, H is a subgp of G, and G/H is finite, then
   |G/H|=p^k.
2. Given a Sylow p subgp K of G and x in G, suppose
   |x|=p^k & x^(-1)Kx=K. Then x is in K.
3. If K is a Sylow p subgp of G and G/K is finite,
   then p cannot divide G/K.

=> To complete the proof, I need to generalize 3 and 
get ‘If H is subgp of G, H contains a Sylow p-subgp of G, and G/H is finite, then p cannot divide G/H.’

Even other way of proof might be a great help to me.
(But I hope you keep in mind that I’m just a Sophomore student...)

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange! please consider to use MathJax to edit your question, and make it more readable. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

Since $|G:N(K)|$ is finite, there is a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ with $N \le N(K) \le G$ and $G/N$ finite.

Now, since $G/N$ is finite, the $p$-group $KN/N$ is contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup $L/N$ of $G/N$. We claim that all elements of order a power of $p$ that lie in $L$ must lie in $K$. To see this, let $KN = L_0 \lhd L_1 \cdots \lhd L_r = L$ be a subnormal series. Suppose by induction that the claim holds for all elements of $L_{i-1}$ for some $i$. Then $K$ consists of the set of all elements of order a power of $p$ that lie in $L_{i-1}$, so it is characteristic in $L_{i-1}$, and hence normal in $L_i$. So all such elements in $L_i$ must also lie in $K$, since otherwise, together with $K$, they would generate a larger $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Now if $P$ is any Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, applying Sylow's Theorem in the finite group $G/N$, there exists $g \in G$ with $g^{-1}Pg \le L$, and so by the preceding paragraph $g^{-1}Pg \le K$ and hence $g^{-1}Pg=K$.

Comment: I think that you cannot say that ‘K is characteristis in KN’. Since G is an infinite gp, Cl(K) (the conjugacy class of K in G) does not always contain every Sylow p-subgp.(Actually this is what we are trying to prove.)

Comment: $K$ consists of all elements of $KN$ whose order is a power of $p$, so it is characteristic in $KN$.

Comment: I understood that K is characteristic in KN. I even understood why this fact leads us to all elements order a power of p that normalize KN must contained in K. But I still cannot understand why this fact leads us to conclude that KN/N is a Sylow p-subgp of G/N. I hope you explain this for me. :)

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are right. For some reason I was assuming that $G$ is a torsion group. I have replaced the claim with a more complicated claim.

Comment: But how can we set that finite normal series that leads KN to L ?

Comment: Oh, I think that I got how to construct that finite subnormal series. First, since L/N is a finite p-gp, there is a finite subnormal series C0, ... Ck, which leads KN/N to L/N(this is base on the fact that every maximal subgp of finite p-gp is normal.)For each i, let Li={g| Ng in Ci}. Then since C0,...,Ck is a subnormal series which leads KN/N to L/N, it follows that L0,...,Lk is a subnormal series that leads KN into L. Am I right?